# Nested promises to achieve sequential execution

Tags: javascript, nested, promise

I have a function that calls itself a couple of times when a promise is resolved, and when it is done calling itself, it resolves the promise like so:

```
var counter = 0;
function runStep(past_resolved_content) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  //do something different with counter
  if (counter < reference ) {
    counter++;
    var step_ran = somePromiseReturningFunction();
    step_ran.then(runStep);
  } else {
    resolve("message");     
  }
```

From what I can tell, the function does what I want, it will call the `somePromiseReturningFunction()` correctly and in the desired order.
I have a second function that must call `runStep()` and continue execution when the promise returned by it is resolved.

```
function executeAllSteps() {
  runStep().then(
    function(){
      console.log("resolved outer promise");
  });
}
```

My problem is that I cannot make the `executeAllSteps` function work as desired. I have tried several syntax for the `.then` but nothing produced the desired output.

Either the content is called immediately, without the promise resolving ( when I write it like this: `runStep().then(console.log("resolved outer promise"));`, or never at all.

**Does anyone know how to correct this function?**

Note: I need to use the native javascript promise implementation.

Comment: What promise library (if any) are you using? Some have a convenience method for this. Also, you don't need a promise constructor in your example - just returning the `then` and chaining.

Comment: In am not using a promise library, just the native promise implementation.

Comment: I'm on my way out to the pub, if no one posts an answer until tomorrow I will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you go inside the `if (counter < reference ) {` condition, you will never resolve the promise that you created in that invocation of `runStep()` and thus the `.then()` handler in `executeAllSteps()` never fires.  You need to find a place in `runStep()` where you resolve the promise you created for each invocation of `runStep()`, whether or not you've reach your counter max.

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but you could do this:

```
var counter = 0;
function runStep(past_resolved_content) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //do something different with counter
    if (counter < reference ) {
      counter++;
      var step_ran = somePromiseReturningFunction();
      step_ran.then(runStep).then(resolve);          // <== change made here
    } else {
      resolve("message");     
    }
  });
}
```

Logically, this will call call the first `runStep()` which will execute `somePromiseReturningFunction()` and when that is done (when it's promise is resolved), it will call a nested `runStep()` and when that inner `runStep` resolves, the outer one will resolve itself.  So what will happen is you will nest several calls to `runStep()` until your `counter` gets to the `reference` value and then that inner `runStep` will resolve itself.  That will allow the next-most outer `runStep` to resolve itself, then the next most outer `runStep` to resolve itself continuing until it gets to the most outer `runStep` which will resolve itself and then all then `.then()` handler in `executeAllSteps()` which it sounds like is what you want.

---

I suspect that if I understood more what you're really trying to accomplish rather than this somewhat abstract code example, then I could probably find a much cleaner way to do this, but I don't really follow what you want to do in what conditions.

---

There are several different approaches you could take that will use existing promises rather than always creating new ones.  Here's one idea:

```
var counter = 0;
function runStep(past_resolved_content) {
    //do something different with counter
    if (counter < reference ) {
        counter++;
        return somePromiseReturningFunction().then(runStep);
    } else {
        // return a resolved promise with your message
        return Promise.resolve("message");
        });
    }
}
```

---

You could also avoid calling runStep recursively when the counter has reached its value which simplifies things a bit (assumes you don't call runStep the first time when counter has already exceeded the value):

```
var counter = 0;
function runStep(past_resolved_content) {
    counter++;
    return somePromiseReturningFunction().then(function(data) {
        if (counter < reference) {
            return runStep(data);
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Working demo of this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PfEV2/

---

And, if you don't need to manipulate the `counter` variable as the process unfolds, then you could do it in a loop too where `runStep` doesn't have to call itself and the counter doesn't have to be a public variable:

```
function runStep() {
    var p = Promise.resolve();
    for (var counter = 0; counter < reference; counter++) {
        p = p.then(somePromiseReturningFunction);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/33ZZ6/

Comment: @SimpleJ - That's a good idea.  I added something like that and another idea to my answer.  Both are methods of using the existing promises rather than always creating new ones (which seems like a generally good thing to do).

Comment: `Promise.defer()` is non-standard and will likely be removed from the browsers that do implement it in the future. Instead, use `p = Promise.resolve()` and chain to that instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - OK, I changed the example to that.  How are you supposed to get an unresolved deferred that you can resolve later externally to the constructor callback?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure if you're asking about your specific example in the question (it's not required here) or the general use case. You can always extract a deferred from a promise constructor (via closure) but in practice that's never really required (at least, I haven't seen a real use case).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I'm just asking for my own understanding.  How would you extract a deferred from a promise constructor?

Comment: `var d = {}; var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ d.resolve = resolve; d.reject = reject; });` you can now access d the deferred and p the promise. Although as I said earlier this is kind of pointless in my opinion.

Comment: First part (second .then) has solved my question. I was actually only resolving the 'lowest' runStep and not resolving all the way upstream.